# Qubole Kinesis Connector for Spark structured streaming throws an error

Tags: apache-spark, qubole

We are using Qubole Kinesis Connector (jar) for Spark structured streaming. This used to work fine but suddenly, it is throwing an error "S3 filesystem not found".

We could use the KCL but we need to test it for foreachbatch. Are there any other available Kinesis connectors available that provide seamless writing operations?

Comment: can you stick in the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

@Lightning-Analytics, Please share the full stack trace and respective qubole streaming command-id if any.